# Android NoSuchMethodException: callDrawGLFunction

Tags: android, webview, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I find the method is reanme to callDrawGLFunction2 at the android version of 5.1.0 . And add the class of com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewDelegateFactory at the same time.
But i don't know how to fix the bug. can anyone have idea.

full stack:

```
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
... 25 more
Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid reflection
at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProvider(WebViewFactory.java)
at android.webkit.WebView.getFactory(WebView.java)
at android.webkit.WebView.ensureProviderCreated(WebView.java)
at android.webkit.WebView.setOverScrollMode(WebView.java)
at android.view.View.init(View.java)
at android.view.View.init(View.java)
at android.view.ViewGroup.init(ViewGroup.java)
at android.widget.AbsoluteLayout.init(AbsoluteLayout.java)
at android.webkit.WebView.init(WebView.java)
at android.webkit.WebView.init(WebView.java)
at android.webkit.WebView.init(WebView.java)
at android.webkit.WebView.init(WebView.java)
... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid reflection
at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewDelegateFactory$Api21CompatibilityDelegate.init(WebViewDelegateFactory.java:258)
at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider.init(WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider.java:2106)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1690)
... 39 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: callDrawGLFunction [long]
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:671)
at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewDelegateFactory$Api21CompatibilityDelegate.init(WebViewDelegateFactory.java:246)
... 42 more
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class android.webkit.WebView
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java)
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not application error.
 The bug is all report from the device of sdk 22. But the method is already rename in that version.

I send email to google developer who rename the method from callDrawGLFunction to callDrawGLFunction2. I got some reply:

"Api21CompatibilityDelegate means webview believes it's running on 21. Renaming callDrawGLFunction happened *after* API21, hence webview is trying look for the old name."

So It's obvious device rom bug.

Comment: What is the fix for it then?

Comment: @q126y Sorry, my conclusion is that not application error, is the error of FrameWork tier. so we can't fix that.